# Create modified HFONT from HFONT

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I using the Win32 API and C/C++. I have a HFONT and want to use it to create a new HFONT. The new font should use the exact same font metrics except that it should be bold. Something like:

```
HFONT CreateBoldFont(HFONT hFont) {
    LOGFONT lf;
    GetLogicalFont(hFont, &lf);
    lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    return CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
}
```

The "GetLogicalFont" is the missing API (as far as I can tell anyway). Is there some other way to do it? Preferrably something that works on Windows Mobile 5+.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want to use the [GetObject function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
GetObject ( hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf );
```

Answer (score 13):

Something like this - note that error checking is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

```
static HFONT CreateBoldWindowFont(HWND window)
{
    const HFONT font = (HFONT)::SendMessage(window, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
    LOGFONT fontAttributes = { 0 };
    ::GetObject(font, sizeof(fontAttributes), &fontAttributes);
    fontAttributes.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

    return ::CreateFontIndirect(&fontAttributes);
}

static void PlayWithBoldFont()
{
    const HFONT boldFont = CreateBoldWindowFont(someWindow);
    .
    . // Play with it!
    .
    ::DeleteObject(boldFont);
}
```

Comment: I came looking for copper and I found gold!